# Adding a new log attribute in nginx logs after modifying an existing one

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress

I have an Ingress-NGINX Controller chart for Kubernetes having its `log-format-upstream` configured as:

```
disable-access-log: "false" 
log-format-upstream: '{"time": "$time_iso8601", "remote_addr": "$proxy_protocol_addr", "x_forwarded_for": "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for", "request_id": "$req_id",
  "remote_user": "$remote_user", "bytes_sent": $bytes_sent, "request_time": $request_time, "status": $status, "vhost": "$host", "request_proto": "$server_protocol",
  "path": "$uri", "request_query": "$args", "request_length": $request_length, "duration": $request_time,"method": "$request_method", "http_referrer": "$http_referer",
  "http_user_agent": "$http_user_agent" }'
ingressClass: nginx
```

Assuming, that the path of the request exists in fields like `$http_referrer`  or `$uri` such as `/questions/12345678/details`.

What I want is to include another log attribute say `uri_category` which contains uri paths but with any dynamic numbers such as `12345678` replaced with a static text such as `USER_ID` irrespective where this variable information appears in the path.

So in above example I would want the new attribute `uri_category` to have a value of `/questions/USER_ID/details`.

Is it possible to achieve this using log formatter and if yes how?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) to create the `uri_category` variable which can then be passed to `log-format-upstream`.

```
map $uri $uri_category {
    ~(questions/)([0-9]+)(/details)$ $1USER_ID$3;
}
log-format-upstream: '{"time": "$time_iso8601", "remote_addr": "$proxy_protocol_addr", "x_forwarded_for": "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for", "request_id": "$req_id",
  "remote_user": "$remote_user", "bytes_sent": $bytes_sent, "request_time": $request_time, "status": $status, "vhost": "$host", "request_proto": "$server_protocol",
  "path": "$uri", "request_query": "$args", "request_length": $request_length, "duration": $request_time,"method": "$request_method", "http_referrer": "$http_referer",
  "http_user_agent": "$http_user_agent", "uri_category": "$uri_category" }'
```